# ObjectMapper: Dictionary key as value in Mapped objects

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

```
{
  "3": {
    "title": "something"
  },
  "28": {
    "title": "something else"
  }
}
```

How do i cast this json to array of Content objects using ObjectMapper?

```
struct Content: Mappable {
    var id: String? //Expected value is 3, 28
    var title: String? //Expected value is "something", "something else"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you´re looking for something like this:

JSON - Model:

```
let content = Mapper<Content>().map(JSONString)
```

Model - JSON:

```
let json = Mapper().toJSONString(content, prettyPrint: true)
```

And before you can use it you need to change your `Content Model` to the following:

```
struct Content: Mappable {
    var id: String? //Expected value is 3, 28
    var title: String? //Expected value is "something", "something else"

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        title <- map["title"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3:
First get all the keys from this Dictionary like this

```
keysArray = Array(dict.keys)
```

Now loop through this keysArray & you will get all the keys from this dictionary like

```
for i in 0..<keysArray.count {
    if let key = keysArray[i] as? String {
       //get your key here
        if let singleObject = dict[key] as? [String: Any] {
           if let value = singleObject["title"] as? String {
              //get you value
              // get both key & value. Now map it. Hope you get it.
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.